# Let $n$ be a prime number. Consider $\mathbb U_n$ which is the set of roots of unity.

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Let $n$ be a prime number. Consider $\mathbb U_n$ which is the set of roots of unity, i.e. the solutions of the equation $z^n=1$, more precisely  $\mathbb U_n = ${$1,\epsilon , \epsilon^2 , ... , \epsilon^{n-1}$} , where $\epsilon = \cos \frac{2k \pi}{n}+i\sin{2k \pi}{n} ,k={0,1,2,...,n-1}$. My question is if $n$ is prime , then how many subsets of $\mathbb U_n$ have the property that the sum of all the elements from the subset is 0 ? I think the answer would be 1(the the whole set ), but I'm not sure and there might be more.I need someone's confirmation/contradiction. Thank you all !

Comment: @joriki At the end of the answer, it is concluded that for primes, only the full set is good (using degree of polynomials). This question asks whether there exist more subsets, which is answered in the last paragraph of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is prime, then each of $\epsilon^k$, $1\leq k\leq n-1$ is a root of

$$p(z)=z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}+\dots+z+1.$$
This polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and hence it is the minimal polynomial of $\epsilon$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Suppose for some elements of the set $A=\{\epsilon, \epsilon^2, \dots \epsilon^{n-1}, 1\}$, we get sum equal to zero, say
$$\epsilon^{k_1}+\epsilon^{k_2}+\dots+\epsilon^{k_r}=0,$$
where all $k_i$ are distinct and $0\leq k_i\leq  n-1$. Assuming without loss of generality that $k_1$ is the highest value, then this implies $\epsilon$ would satisfy another polynomial of degree $k_1 \leq n-1$. Hence, this new polynomial must be $p(z)$ itself as this new polynimial is monic and the minimal polynomial is always unique and hence the above sum must involve all the elements of the set $A$.

Comment: $p$ is the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial.

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Comment: Gauss proved that they're irreducible.

Comment: Thanks for your help !